# Distinguish between different linux distros in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system

Basically I want to be able to run different code depending on what os you have.

I've found out that the `os.platform()` function will return "win32", "win64", "darwin", or "linux" (possibly others?), but I can't seem to get any more specific information.

Ideally I want to be able to tell if Gnome, Unity, KDE, or some other desktop environment is being used.

Comment: I'm confused, which is it that you want? OS, distro, or desktop environment?

Comment: @mscdex I guess for this project just the desktop environment, but it would be nice to know how to get other info also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the active desktop environment/window manager is not a node-specific problem. There are [different approaches](https://askubuntu.com/a/281535) (some better than others) that include using `pgrep` to check running process names against known DE/WM binary names and using other tools such as `HardInfo` or [`wmctrl`](https://askubuntu.com/a/125066).

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was a bash scripts from mscottnielsen. It seems to use the best of many different commands to find out what desktop environment is being used. Unfortunetally, it's kind of hard to figure out the exact string that gets outputed by it (It doesn't say anywhere what strings get outputed), but other then that it does the job.

See the script [here](https://github.com/mscottnielsen/homedir/blob/master/skel/bin/desktop_session.sh).